# How to parse posted value?

Tags: php, html, arrays, parsing, checkbox

I have the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pay[]"  value="
               <?php 
                         echo $invoiceArr[$record_count].";";
                         echo $TotalArr[$record_count].";";
                         echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
                  ?>
                  " onClick="checkTotal()"/>
```

How can I parse:

```
       echo $invoiceArr[$record_count].";";
       echo $TotalArr[$record_count].";";
       echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
```

When the form is being submited with POST?

Many thanks

How can I get only one element

```
   echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
```

and pass it into :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[]");
```

Thanks mates

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you having?  Also, why not break it into hidden inputs and then just use the checkbox as a "should I read those hidden inputs?" flag?

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `pay[]` as form name, I believe you try to do arrayed form input. To read arrayed form input, you just have to read it by using it's key.

**A little bit of background:**

You can create array like this:

```
$data[] = "1";
$data[] = "2";
```

From code above, you'll ended up with array `$data` with 2 element:

```
print_r($data);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

**Back to your problem.** To parse it, all you have to do is, loop through it:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['pay'] ); $i++)
{
    $data = $_POST['pay'][ $i ];
    list($invoice, $total, $amount_due) = explode(";", $data);
    echo "Incoive: $invoice || Total: $total || Amount due: $amount_due";
}
```

Comment: how can I display invoice,total and ammount due ? the code above only displays ammount...?

Comment: Incoive:630.03 || Total: || Amount due:

Comment: `for( $i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['pay'] ); $i++)
   {
    $data = $_POST['pay'][ $i ];
    list($invoice, $total, $amount_due) = explode(";", $data);
    echo "Incoive:". $invoice." || Total:". $total." || Amount due:". $amount_due."<br>";
   }`

Comment: please check your HTML, particularly the `<input type="checkbox" name="pay[]"  value="` part. is it containing all the values you want?

Comment: yes it is, I changed to split and it works, what should I do with `var elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[]");` and I want to use `echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];`
 only as variable

Comment: give id to your element `<input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" id="pay1" value="">` and use that id `document.getElementsById("pay1");`

Comment: doesn't work, I only need one element from pay[]...? if I use "pay1" I call all pay[] then ?

Comment: i want to use `echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];` only from `pay[]`

Comment: can I do something like this : `       var elements = document.getElementsByName("pay[][2]");` ?

Comment: no, you can't and this is has already gone way beyond the scope of this question. You can close this question and create another one that represent your other problem (the reading html part)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like unusual way to do things but you can parse it by exploding.

```
list($invoice, $total, $amount_due) = explode(";", $_POST['pay'][0]);
```

Comment: how can I display the result ? echo $invoice ?

Comment: Basically yes but look at silent's answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would change the name of the input to `name=pay`

Then in php you would do the following:

```
$data = explode(';', $_POST['pay']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `var_dump` on `$_GET` or on `$_POST` and you'll see.
Besides, I think you are mis-understanding what you try to do.
You need three elements with the name `pay[]`, and each of them will have only ONE of the values you have

```
$invoiceArr[$record_count]
$TotalArr[$record_count]
$amount_dueArr[$record_count]
```